# Understanding declared parameters in my Conv2d layer of my convolutional neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, machine-learning-model, convolutional-neural-network

I am trying to understand the architecture of my keras model implemented by the sequential model.

Here is a piece of the code :

```
model = Sequential([
    #block1
    layers.Conv2D(nfilter,(3,3),padding="same",name="block1_conv1",input_shape=(64,64,3)),
    layers.Activation("relu"),
    layers.BatchNormalization(), .......
```

My question is why the two parameters input_shape and name are declared in the layer conv2D while they are not included in the set of defined parmeters for Conv2D() in this link https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot the `name` and `input_shape` come from the [Layer class](https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/#layer-class) which Conv2D inherited. In the doc you provide, they are implicitly in `**kwargs`

Comment: I found the name parmeter but input_shape no